# How can I add .NET framework to my project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, frameworks

Currently I'm working on a Project where my first Form was not .NET framework. I'm trying to add a Windows Form App (.NET framework) to this project but I can't find anywhere on the internet how to do this.

When creating this project, instead of clicking on 'Windows Form App (.NET framework)' I clicked on the other one
[image]

Is there any way to add the .net framework to my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-target your project by right-clicking in Visual Studio and choosing Edit Project or opening it in a text editor.

You are looking for the `<TargetFramework>` element. I would hazard a guess it is currently set to `net5.0-windows` updating it to `NET48` will change the target framework.

You may have to fix some compilation errors if you have used any features from .NET 5 that are not available in .NET 4.8 but that can't be helped

Answer (score 0):

You should create another project, and this time select the right target framework. The one you selected runs on .net core.

Comment: Problem is: I've been working on this project for the past 4 months

Comment: just go to properties on each project and change TargetFramework from netcore31 to netframework472 or whatever version you need

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply just add the .NET Framework to your project. Those types are fundamentally different.
Since you "only" have one form so far, I suggest you to create a new project within your current solution (right click on solution, add project) and then select the "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)" and rebuild your existing form.

There are tools to convert the ASP form to an ASP.NET form, something like this https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=aspclassiccompiler (I have not used it but it seems to fit your problem) but I would say its much easier to recreate your single existing form.

Comment: I have worked on this project for the past 4 months, there's 11 forms currently, not only one sadly.  I'll check on this tool to see if it can help me, thanks.